# how to get d3.event.Y as location in a <g> element

Tags: d3.js, svg, drag

In d3.js V4 the d3.event.y gives the event y location in a SVG element but I need the location of the event as it is in a G element. For example if a mouse is at the top of the G element than d3.event.y should be zero. But in my attempt it is only zero if the mouse is at the top of the SVG element. Here is my attempt: [jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/nakejewuqe/1/edit?html,js,output) - try dragging the 'water' line up and down. The water line never matches the mouse dragging. My SVG will scale with the width of the page so I cannot hard code values.

D3 V4 code:

```
var high = null;
d3.select('#bfG').call(
  d3.drag().on('start', function () {
    //get the real height of the <g> element
    high = this.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  }).on('drag', function () {
    // % of the location relative to the <g> height
    var p = (d3.event.y / high) * 100;
    var q = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, p));
    d3.select('#stop1').attr('offset', q + '%');
    d3.select('#stop2').attr('offset', q + '%');
  })
);
```

Comment: At all scale level this works fine `var p = d3.event.y - 25;` http://jsbin.com/yodagoxemo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: That does work for that shape but not when my shape height changes: http://jsbin.com/yecazad/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getBBox method to get y and height properties of the shape in the user space and then calculate offset:

```
var bbox = this.getBBox()
var p = (d3.event.y - bbox.y) / bbox.height * 100
```

examples: [1](http://jsbin.com/kexunajimi/1/edit), [2](http://jsbin.com/voramuzeru/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I must say your code is very intresting.

Well, I prepare to recommend you to use [d3.mouse(container)](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#d3_mouse), then I think there is no difference between **d3.mouse(container)** and **d3.event.y** in this case, because you didn't transform the g element so the g element share the same coordinate system with svg.

I mean *d3.mouse(this)[1]* and *d3.event.y* will produce same value in this case.